# Integer to string conversion

Tags: java

Normally I used one of these methods while converting an integer to a string:

- `Integer.toString(i)` or
- `String.valueOf(i)`
  while `i` is an integer-value.

Are both ways are correct?

Comment: What makes you feel it might not be correct. Does it sometimes fail, or do something suprising? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: You should do the one which is more obvious to you.  I use `"" + i` which is shorter, though slower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both ways are the same :

```
/**
 * Returns the string representation of the {@code int} argument.
 * <p>
 * The representation is exactly the one returned by the
 * {@code Integer.toString} method of one argument.
 *
 * @param   i   an {@code int}.
 * @return  a string representation of the {@code int} argument.
 * @see     java.lang.Integer#toString(int, int)
 */
public static String valueOf(int i) {
    return Integer.toString(i);
}
```